# Существует ли таблица в mysql?

Tags: mysqli, php

При запросе к несуществующей таблице интерпретатор выдает ошибку. Можно ли как-то с помощью php определить заранее существование таблицы? Без использования символа подавления ошибки @?

Comment: не знаю, правильно ли это или нет, но посмотрите [тут][1]

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008299/check-if-mysql-table-exists-or-not

Comment: @DreamChild, да, так и есть...

Comment: раз уж под аналогичным ответом, что вы приняли как верный, развернулась такая дискуссия, то я бы рекомендовал посмотреть и другие ответы по ссылке, что я вам привел. Может, они не deprecated

Comment: @DreamChild, по сути depricated само расширение, а сущность и формат sql по-моему не изменились...

Comment: @Deus deprEcated, а не deprIcated) Впрочем, это небольшое занудство

Comment: там есть небольшой pitfall, иногда привелегии на SELECT  есть, а на доступ к information schema нет. может DESC было-бы лучше.

Comment: @DreamChild, я сам такой же зануда. Спасибо за пинок!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'"))==1) 
     echo "Table exists";
else echo "Table does not exist";
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto, вы это уже полгода твердите! ))) Результата никакого!

Comment: есть результат.  некоторые задумываются.